# How does a smooth functor guarantee the existence of another smooth vector bundle from a given one?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, functors

I am trying to understand the following definition of *smooth* functors on the category of finite dimensional vector spaces (in the context of smooth vector bundle theory):

Let $\mathsf{Vec}$ be the category whose objects are finite-dimensional real vector
spaces, and whose morphisms are linear isomorphisms. If $\mathcal F$ is a covariant functor from $\mathsf{Vec}$ to itself, for each finite-dimensional vector space $V$ we get a map $\mathcal F:GL(V)\to GL(\mathcal F(V))$ sending each isomorphism $A:V\to V$ to the induced isomorphism $\mathcal F(A):\mathcal F(V)\to\mathcal F(V)$. We say $\mathcal F$ is a **smooth functor** if this map is smooth for every $V\in\mathsf{Ob(Vec)}$.

I am trying to prove the following:

> Given a smooth vector bundle $E\to M$ and a smooth functor $\mathcal F:\mathsf{Vec}\to \mathsf{Vec}$, show that there is another smooth vector bundle $\mathcal F(E)\to M$ whose fiber at each point $p\in M$ is $\mathcal F(E_p)$, where $E_p$ denotes the fiber of $p$ over $M$ w.r.t. the bundle $E\to M$.

My issue is I don't quite understand how to use the smoothness of the functor $\mathcal F$ to obtain a new vector bundle $\mathcal F(E)\to M$. What are the local trivializations in such a bundle? How would one go about showing that the trivializations are diffeomorphisms?

My guess is that since we start with a smooth bundle $E\to M$, we somehow manage to express the trivializations and projections for $\mathcal F(E)\to M$ in terms of $\mathcal F$ and the ones for $E\to M$. Then smoothness of all maps would follow from smoothness of $\mathcal F$ and $E\to M$. But I have no clue how to actually accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Write down cocycles in $GL_n$ defining $E$, then apply $F$ to those cocycles. The more general fact is that if $f : G \to H$ is a (smooth) homomorphism of Lie groups then it induces a map from smooth principal $G$-bundles to smooth principal $H$-bundles (and the argument is the same).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : I'm currently only studying smooth manifold theory, and the category theory stuff is just introduced along the way. So, I am not familiar with the definition of a *cocycle* yet. Is there a different way to state your above comment?

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is another name for the transition functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle#Transition_functions

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : Yes, thanks! I am very familiar with transition functions. So, what you say is: When we consider the transition functions of $\mathrm{GL}(E_p)$ for each $p\in M$ and apply the functor $\mathcal F$ on these "matrices", we obtain the transition functions for the induced bundle?

Comment: Yes, that's right.